# Getting input values in HTML

Tags: html, forms, input

I need help with this simple thing. I have a multiple selection input box and I want to get the values of the selected parameter using javascript. The problem is, that when I use:

```
x=document.form.box.value;
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form name="form">
<select name="box" multiple>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

I always get just the first selected option. I need to get the values of all selected options as a string, ideally separated by commas. If I for example choose A, I get A, if B, I get B, but when I choose A and B, I get A again.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: @koala_dev no, that wasn't a multiselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give your select box and ID, this will make it accessible via standard calls:

```
<select name="box" id="box" multiple>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Then you can loop thru individual options, appending only selected ones:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("box")
var sResult = "";

for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++) {
  if (sel.options[i].selected){
      sResult += sel.options[i].value + ','
  }
}

if (sResult.length > 1)  sResult = sResult.substring(0,sResult.length-1);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LGCY6/2/